# Keep progress bar visible while writing to stdout

Tags: powershell, progress-bar

I have an PowerShell installation script that calls several other scripts that write to `stdout` as they progress. It is impossible to determine how far along the installation script has gotten by looking at the `stdout`. Therefore, I would like to show a progress bar.

I tried using `Write-Progress`, but as soon as some lines are written to `stdout`, the progress bar shifts upwards and disappears out of view.

Is there a way to make the progress bar stick to the top of the terminal, and not go out of view? The things written to `stdout` may portray value, so I don't want to just throw the output away in order to keep the progress bar visible.

Comment: Not really, how the progress bar is rendered is entirely the responsibility of the _host application_ (eg. `powershell.exe`), not the PowerShell language engine itself (it just emits the progress records, nothing more)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Ok. Is there a way to capture what is written to `stdout`? Then I can flush the content for instance every second, and repeat the `Write-Progress` after every flush.

Answer (score 0):

Today i had a similar case and found your question unresolved.
I came up with something like this. Hope it helps.
Basically i start a background Job with my long running Task and save its id. I Do `Receive-Job` every 2 second to get its output and then i reprint my `Write-Progress`

```
Function Replace-GhorsePlots {
    Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity "Replacing Ghorse Plots" -Status "Starting" -PercentComplete 0
    $PlotCount = Get-GhorsePlots | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
    $i=0
    Get-GhorsePlots | ForEach-Object {
        $PlotFile = $_
        Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity "Replacing Ghorse Plots" -Status ("{0} of {1} Plots replaced. Replacing {2}" -f $i, $PlotCount, $PlotFile.Name) -PercentComplete ($i / $PlotCount * 100)
        #Remove on Ghorse Plot and instead plot one Bladebit Plot
        $NewPlotDestPath=$PlotFile.DirectoryName.Replace("/ghorse", "/bladebit")
        # Write-Host("Replacing " + $PlotFile.FullName + " with a new plot in " + $NewPlotDestPath)
        Remove-Item -Path $PlotFile.FullName -Confirm:$false
        # Create PlotJob to reference to the ID later
        $PlotJob = Start-Job -ArgumentList @($NewPlotDestPath) -ScriptBlock {
            param(
                $NewPlotDestPath
            )
            # To be sure we have the Module on the new process
            Import-Module -Name ChiaShell -DisableNameChecking
            # This lasts really long and prints a lot on stdout
            Invoke-BladebitPlotter -DestDir $NewPlotDestPath -Count 1
            # Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        }

        #Wait for PlotJob to finish and show progress
        do {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
            $PlotJob = Get-Job -Id $PlotJob.Id
            Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity "Replacing Ghorse Plots" -Status ("{0} of {1} Plots replaced. Replacing {2}" -f $i, $PlotCount, $PlotFile.Name) -PercentComplete ($i / $PlotCount * 100)
            Receive-Job -Job $PlotJob
        } while ($PlotJob.State -eq "Running")
        # Finished -> Remove
        Remove-Job -Id $PlotJob.Id
        $i++
    }
    Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity "Replacing Ghorse Plots" -Status "Finished" -PercentComplete 100 -Completed
    
}
```